# webpage download using cURL utility - proxy cycle issue

Tags: windows, unix, networking, curl, proxy

I am trying to access google.com from my work using cURL for windows 32-bit(with SSH version). I am connecting via my company's proxy server but I am getting 400 proxy cycle detected error. Could someone please let me know why I am getting this error. The command & error message are as follows(Proxy IP changed to XXXX):

**Command:**

```
%curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0b7pre) Gecko/20100925 Firefox/4.0b7pre"  -v --proxy-ntlm XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080 -U name:password -I http://www.google.com
```

**Output:**

```
Enter proxy password for user 'name':
* Rebuilt URL to:  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/
* About to connect() to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
* Adding handle: conn: 0xcb0520
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0xcb0520) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port 8080 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0b7pre) Gecko/20100925 Firefox/4.0b7pre
> Host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Cycle Detected
HTTP/1.1 400 Cycle Detected
< Date: Mon, 25 Nov 2013 11:56:06 GMT
Date: Mon, 25 Nov 2013 11:56:06 GMT
< Via: 1.1 localhost.localdomain
Via: 1.1 localhost.localdomain
< Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-store
< Content-Type: text/html
Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Language: en
Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 288
Content-Length: 288

<
* Connection #0 to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX left intact
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.google.com/
* Adding handle: conn: 0xcb12f8
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 1 (0xcb12f8) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 80 (#1)
*   Trying 173.194.115.50...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 173.194.115.51...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 173.194.115.49...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 173.194.115.48...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 173.194.115.52...
* Connection refused
* Failed connect to www.google.com:80; Connection refused
* Closing connection 1
curl: (7) Failed connect to www.google.com:80; Connection refused
```

For what it's worth, I am able to connect to google.com via browser using the said proxy address. And I am sure that I am giving the password(for the proxy) correctly.

Comment: try with https with google instead of using http, this may work, try it out

Comment: Also again check that you are sending request only once, continuos request may cause problems

Comment: you are providing username and password, do you want to login at somewhere???, i mean in gmail or anywhere else, if you want to do that, then you have to require url, and also some other options in different way(instead of usual way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the proxy via --proxy parameter or -x parameter not via --proxy-ntlm, try this, please

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0b7pre) Gecko/20100925 Firefox/4.0b7pre" -L --proxy http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 --proxy-ntlm -U name:password http://www.google.com
```

If you enter in a new redirect cycle you can try without -L parameter or set the --max-redirs parameter.

[cURL manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: Thanks. This IS it. Sorry for the late acceptance. Have been inactive for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are being knocked back due to authentication. Your work proxy likely requires authentication before it will allow you to access websites through it.

If your work uses Active Directory SSO (Single Sign On), try the following with your domain username and password:

```
curl --ntlm --user username:password http://www.google.com
```

Or not, try the following for basic auth:

```
curl --user username:password http://www.google.com
```